# Time-zone issue python function-app on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-function-app

I am running multiple python function apps through a standard service plan and I am not able to change the time-zone to the desired values. I am located in Amsterdam the Netherlands and have the changed the "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" to "W. Europe Standard Time" but all the timestamps are still two hours behind. It looks like this "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" field is completely ignored. Changing it to other random values also does not do anything in my case.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What is you Function platform? WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE is not currently supported on the Linux Consumption plan as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-time-zones)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the standard service plan running a Linux function-app. I changed the "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" from "W. Europe Standard Time" to "Europe/Amsterdam" without any result. So both versions do not seem to work in my case?

Comment: When you say 'standard service plan', what do you mean? There are 3 types of plan -  Consumption plan, Premium plan, and Dedicated (App Service) plan  https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am using both the Premium Plan and Dedicated plan with different function-apps. I do not use the consumption plan.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux plans, WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE values are based on TZ database entries
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

For W. Europe Standard Time the equivalent TZ value is Europe/Amsterdam. Try setting WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE to Europe/Amsterdam.

Comment: Just noticed you mentioned Europe/Amsterdam didn't work either. I think the app name would be helpful in debugging this futher.

Please share the app name using https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately at 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues or here.